# Returning the result of a javascript function to a variable in Blazor server

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

I have a method like below. I will like to call a javascript function and return the result
in to a variable

```
        private async Task Checker()
        {
           var result = (await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("checkNullValues");
        }
```

Here is the javascript function

```
        function checkNullValues() {
            return $('.k-grid-container .excelGridCell').length === 0 && $('.k-textbox').length == 0;
        }
```

In the Checker method, I kept getting this error message

"cannot implicitly convert type void to string"

Is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you expect to receive values from Javascript function using JSInterop, you should use InvokeAsync method instead of InvokeVoidAsync, indicating the datatype expected to retrieve. For example I suppose that you want to receive a bool, so:

```cs
private async Task Checker()
{
    var result = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("checkNullValues");
}
```