# How to return value from Javascript function to C# Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, blazor

I have a Blazor project and now i face the problem with returning of double value from Javascript function to C# Blazor. I call Javascript function in `.razor` file through `IJSRuntime` and get null value. I try to serialize value in Javascript and return it but it doesn't work.

It's my Javascript function:

```js
window.DetectSpeed = () => {
    var userImageLink =
        "https://mobilesyrup.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/starlink-header-how-to-2048x1151.jpg";
    var time_start, end_time;

    var downloadSize = 898080;
    var downloadImgSrc = new Image();

    downloadImgSrc.onload = function () {
        end_time = new Date().getTime();
        displaySpeed();
    }

    time_start = new Date().getTime();
    downloadImgSrc.src = userImageLink;
    document.write("time start: " + time_start);
    document.write("<br>");

    function displaySpeed() {
        var timeDuration = (end_time - time_start) / 1000;
        var loadedBits = downloadSize * 8;
        var bps = (loadedBits / timeDuration).toFixed(2);
        var speedInKbps = (bps / 1024).toFixed(2);
        var speedInMbps = ((speedInKbps / 1024).toFixed(2)) / 100;
        console.log(speedInMbps);
        var pleasebeadouble = speedInMbps;
        console.log(pleasebeadouble);
        var json = JSON.stringify(pleasebeadouble);
        return json;
    }
}
```

C# Blazor:

```cs
protected bool IsVisible { get; set; }

public List<string> VideoTags = new List<string>();

public void ToggleMenu() => IsVisible = !IsVisible;


protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        //get Video tags
        VideoTags = await videos.GetVideoTagsAsync();

        await service.UpdateCurrentUserAsync();
        string json = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("DetectSpeed");
        double numm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytearrax: " + numm.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRenderAsync was ended in Index.razor");
    }
}
```

When i try to run this code I get this error:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Value cannot be null. 
(Parameter 'value')                                                                                                                                 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')                                                                                                                                               
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(Object 
value, String parameterName)                                                                                                                   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type 
type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)                                                                                                         
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, 
JsonSerializerSettings settings)                                                                                                                 
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)                                                                                                                                                  
at Netflix_clone.Pages.Index.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in 
{PathName}\Index.razor:line 37                           at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask
(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)                                                                        
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]                                                                                                                                                   
Unhandled exception in circuit 
'mDNS20DIiYUvtG_xp81Y2MdG_d4qsDuTGVhzQrIiKrA'.                                                                                                                                      
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')                                                                                                                                               
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(Object 
value, String parameterName)                                                                                                                   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type 
type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)                                                                                                         
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, 
JsonSerializerSettings settings)                                                                                                                 
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)                                                                                                                                                  
at Netflix_clone.Pages.Index.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in 
{PathName}\Index.razor:line 37                           at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask
(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

How to fix it?

I've tried to return it as a double, int, string and a json serialized string.
All have given me more or less the same error.

Comment: You are currently calling a JS function that doesn't return a value. If you run `Window.DetectSpeed()` in the console, what does it return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning the result of a javascript function to a variable in Blazor server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958920/returning-the-result-of-a-javascript-function-to-a-variable-in-blazor-server)

Comment: @KurtHamilton In the console `console.log(pleasebeadouble)` and `console.log(speedInMbps)` print floating-point values. The function works but doesn't return value

Comment: @libertarian1917 "The function works but doesn't return value". Exactly - so why would you expect it to return a value when called from C#?

Comment: As Kurt mentions your `window.DetectSpeed` is the function that's being called by your C# code but that function specifically doesn't return anything, the only thing that returns is your inner function `displaySpeed`, so changing that to `return displaySpeed();` should fix this.

Comment: @RBee Indeed, I haven't seen this before. Unfortunately I won't be able to test this until tomorrow but this seems like the right solution, thanks!

Comment: @maciek I call the function like in this question but as RBee answered the problem is the return in inner function of `window.DetectSpeed`. I'll try to fix it tomorrow, thanks for the help!

Comment: @KurtHamilton I thought it was supposed to return because of `return json` but now I see I've tried to return from inner function `function displaySpeed()`, not from `window.DetectSpeed`. I'll try to fix it tomorrow, thanks for the help!

Comment: @libertarian1917 no worries. I was trying to get you to think about the problem rather than just give you the answer ;). The problem is you'll need to do significantly more work to recreate the actual functionality. You could do the whole thing in C# by downloading the image data using `HttpClient`, tracking the time taken, and converting the byte array into a format suitable for display (which is simple enough to do, but out of scope for this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I fixed you Javascript method so it works as you expected it to. You can easily copy and paste this method into any browser window debug console and run it to test the output which is a JSON stringified version of your 'pleasebeadouble'.

To test in a debug console after adding the above method:
`await DetectSpeed()`

```js
window.DetectSpeed = async () => {
    var time_start, end_time;
    var downloadSize = 898080;
    var userImageLink = "https://mobilesyrup.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/starlink-header-how-to-2048x1151.jpg";
    // download the image 
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        time_start = new Date().getTime();
        var downloadImgSrc = new Image();
        downloadImgSrc.onload = function () {
            end_time = new Date().getTime();
            resolve();
        }
        downloadImgSrc.onerror = function () {
            end_time = new Date().getTime();
            reject();
        }
        downloadImgSrc.src = userImageLink;
    });
    // wait for image download to complete
    await promise;
    // I wouldn't use document.write with blazor...
    //document.write("time start: " + time_start);
    //document.write("<br>");
    var timeDuration = (end_time - time_start) / 1000;
    var loadedBits = downloadSize * 8;
    var bps = (loadedBits / timeDuration).toFixed(2);
    var speedInKbps = (bps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var speedInMbps = ((speedInKbps / 1024).toFixed(2)) / 100;
    console.log(speedInMbps);
    var pleasebeadouble = speedInMbps;
    console.log(pleasebeadouble);
    var json = JSON.stringify(pleasebeadouble);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: This works for me thank you so so much! :D

Comment:  Glad to help.